# How to Deploy Micro Frontends with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation

Hi Everyone,

I have created micro front end applications in angular with the help of angular module federation and everything is working fine . Now I need to create development build and deploy on any local server. I know that how to create build like by using the **ng build** but the problem is how we can connect to the remote applications and what are the required configurations we need to do ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can map your microfrontend apps with their remote urls in webpack prod configuration.

Check out this webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes

You can see that first example is pointing to localhost but you can change that to public url.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

1. Create a Docker file to build all micro apps and run Docker image.
2. For navigation of micro apps use nginx

Solution 2:
If you don't want use Docker, Build apps normally and use express Js as well for navigation to micro apps